# A program like nethogs for udp?

Tags: udp

I use a good program: nethogs,is like a "top" for tcp traffic
someone know something similar for udp?
I want to see the udp bandwitch used by program

Comment: If you only want to monitor, you can use `iptraf`, It's very powerful.

Comment: Mmm...nethogs is better because give me the top apps tcp consuming i want something like this for udp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `ntop`:

> ntop - display top network users

Also :

> ntop shows the current network usage. It displays a list of hosts that are currently using the network and reports information concerning the (IP and non-IP) traffic generated and received by each host. ntop may operate as a front-end collector (sFlow and/or netFlow plugins) or as a stand-alone collector/display program. A web browser is needed to access the information captured by the ntop program.

Comment: I only found `ntopng` in www.ntop.org. It's difficult to install and use. I quit. The application might have changed.

Answer (score 5):

I compiled the last nethogs from the [github](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs) repo and I found that they added UDP too:

> **nethogs -h**
>
> -C : capture TCP and UDP.

just download the master folder from [github](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs) and do `make` to test it...

Comment: Thanks, this made it show traffic more realistically for me. It shows Zoom's traffic though as `root     unknown UDP`.

Comment: Excellent. I was wondering whether a certain computer would be getting the UDP heavy load and it does... I can see it reaches 2Mb/s on that port as well.